# R/R Shiny: ggplot2 dotplot maximum height problem

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have the problem that I have a ggplot dotplot that is reactive to the screensize in my R shiny app.
The problem is that the plot and bins change their width with the window width and the dots scale out of the plot.

here is the part of my code that has this problem

```
d_frame <- df_galaxy
d_frame <- na.omit(d_frame)
d_frame <- scale(d_frame)
d_frame <- d_frame[,c(5,6)]
kmeans_g <- kmeans(d_frame, centers = 5, nstart = 25) 
dfd <- df_galaxy 
dfd$clusterid <- kmeans_g$cluster
split_dfd <- split(dfd[,c(6)],dfd$clusterid)
data <- melt(split_dfd,measure.vars = names(dfd[,c(6)]))
names(data) <- c("variable","value","clusterid")
ggplot(data,aes(x=value,fill=variable)) +
      geom_density(aes(y = ..density.. * (nrow(data))), col = 2,alpha=0.2) + 
      geom_dotplot(binwidth = 12, 
                   stackgroups = TRUE, binpositions="all",
                   aes(fill=clusterid),alpha=0.6,method = "histodot") +
      labs(x=names(dfd[,c(6)]),y="density") + 
      coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,2))
```

The code is in it's own function not inside an output variable because i have to call it multiple time.

packages used in my code (some are irrelevant for this part):

```
library(shiny)
library(LaplacesDemon)
library(ggcleveland)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr) 
library(GGally)
library(tidyverse)
library(cluster)
library(factoextra)
library(gridExtra)
library(vcd)
library(sjmisc)
library(reshape2)
library(ggdist)
```

[ggplot dotplot with dots in plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9eSq.jpg)

[ggplot dotplot with dots out of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0EZH.jpg)

As you can see I need something like a maxheight or reactive binwith relative to my plotwidth.
I am just stuck here and i don't know what to do.

Comment: Have you tried using the height argument of ```plotOutput()```? See ```?plotOutput```.

Comment: I don't want the plot to be at a fixed height. I want the dots to scale properly to the Plots size.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the attribute `session` to Shinys server function:

```
server <- function(input, output, session)
```

and with that you can dynamically access the current width and height of objects in the UI.
With `session$clientData$output_(UI Element ID)_height` you can access the height attribute of the UI Element. `UI Element ID` should be the same as the String you give into a `plotOutput()` in the UI.

My Current Running Solution for my binwidth ist this:

```
binwidth = ((session$clientData$output_galaxydenseclusterplot_height/100)* 15 / 
                     (session$clientData$output_galaxydenseclusterplot_width/100)+
                    (session$clientData$output_galaxydenseclusterplot_width/500)**1.3)
```

galaxydenseclusterplot is one of my renderPlot variables in output:

```
output$galaxydenseclusterplot <- renderPlot({...})
```

As UI element:

```
plotOutput("galaxydenseclusterplot")
```

[Dots on small width inside visible plotting range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7gdv.jpg)

[Dots on larger width inside visible plotting range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6dGC.jpg)

Ideas for optimisation are welcomed and appreciated.

For anyone with similar problems: I hope this helped.